# How to set and handle timeout in Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Spring docs says it is required to configure http client for WebClient manually to set timeouts: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout.
But since WebClient returns reactive Mono, it's possible (api-wise) to apply `.timeout` method.

Does it have the same effect?

Moreover, when one uses `.timeout` method, Reactor's `TimeoutException` is expected. Will the same error appear in the stream if configuration is done manually i.e. will `doOnError(TimeoutException.class, ...)` work?

Comment: Did you try to check this out with Wiremock that will simulate endpoint with a response time longer than a timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My findings**

Setting a timeout in a http client specific way will lead to http client specific exception i.e. `WebClient` doesn't wrap exceptions:

```
@Test
void test() {
    var host = "localhost";
    var endpoint = "/test";
    var port = 8089;
    var timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(3);

    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8089));
    wireMockServer.start();
    WireMock.configureFor(host, wireMockServer.port());

    WireMock.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(endpoint))
        .willReturn(aResponse().withFixedDelay((int) timeout.toMillis())));

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
        .tcpConfiguration(client ->
            client.doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler((int) (timeout.toSeconds() / 2)))
                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler((int) (timeout.toSeconds() / 2)))));

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(format("http://%s:%d", host, port))
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();

    webClient.get().uri(endpoint).retrieve().bodyToMono(Recommendation.class).block();
}
```

This will lead to `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException`.

`.timeout(timeout.dividedBy(2)).block()` leads to regular `TimeoutException` (`java.util.concurrent`) but it's still an open question whether a web client takes care about connections afterwards (probably not).

My solution is to use http client specific configuration to ensure native and correct way to utilize connections while adding new handler that wraps http client related exception into more generic ones (or `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`) so that `WebClient` clients won't depend on provider exceptions.

Comment: You will need these static imports:

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.aResponse;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlEqualTo;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig;

Comment: How did you test the WriteTimeoutException?