# How to test ConnectTimeoutException and WriteTimeoutException from WebClient?

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I've set up connectimeout, readtimeout and writetimeout for my WebClient per [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout).

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(client -> client
                        .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readtimeout))
                                .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(writetimeout)))
                        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectiontimout));
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .baseUrl(cartDataUrl)
                .build();
```

I have written a test case for ReadTimeout like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54784099/1749786). But, need to figure out a way to test ConnectTimeout and WriteTimeout.

Can anyone help me figure out how to test these 2 exceptions?